# Chrome developer tools: is there a way to show what calls the function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Just as in the topic: is there a way to show what calls the function that I want to inspect? I have an issue, where my function is called twice, and I dont know what calls it for the second time...

Thanks,
uksz

Comment: If you drop here the code we might be a help for you.

Comment: look at the call stack

Comment: Call stack - that is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the monitor() command in the console. You are able to monitor function calls and what parameters were passed to it when it was called.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#monitorfunction